# Meilisearch filtering by date doesn't work in production, but does locally

Tags: kubernetes, meilisearch

I have setup Meilisearch on Kubernetes in production following this: https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch-kubernetes
On my local I am using Laravel Sail (but not Scout).

The major differences between my local and production installation is:

- version - local is 1.2, production is 1.4
- number of documents - local has 82K, production has 5.5 mil
- I loaded the documents in local via PHP SDK and in production I uploaded in CSV files of 98MB via cURL.

The setup of the indexes seem to be the same. The basic search and other filters are working and the sorting seem to work.

`curl -X GET 'http://production/indexes/posts/settings'` (I'm using k8s port forwarding to access production - it is not exposed publically)

```
{
  "displayedAttributes": [
    "*"
  ],
  "searchableAttributes": [
    "*"
  ],
  "filterableAttributes": [
    "created_at",
    "doctype",
    "topic_title",
    "user"
  ],
  "sortableAttributes": [
    "created_at"
  ],
  "rankingRules": [
    "words",
    "typo",
    "proximity",
    "attribute",
    "sort",
    "exactness"
  ],
  "stopWords": [],
  "nonSeparatorTokens": [],
  "separatorTokens": [],
  "dictionary": [],
  "synonyms": {},
  "distinctAttribute": null,
  "typoTolerance": {
    "enabled": true,
    "minWordSizeForTypos": {
      "oneTypo": 5,
      "twoTypos": 9
    },
    "disableOnWords": [],
    "disableOnAttributes": []
  },
  "faceting": {
    "maxValuesPerFacet": 100,
    "sortFacetValuesBy": {
      "*": "alpha"
    }
  },
  "pagination": {
    "maxTotalHits": 1000
  }
}
```

`curl -X GET 'http://localhost:7700/indexes/posts/settings'`

```
{
  "displayedAttributes": [
    "*"
  ],
  "searchableAttributes": [
    "*"
  ],
  "filterableAttributes": [
    "created_at",
    "doctype",
    "topic_title",
    "user"
  ],
  "sortableAttributes": [
    "created_at"
  ],
  "rankingRules": [
    "words",
    "typo",
    "proximity",
    "attribute",
    "sort",
    "exactness"
  ],
  "stopWords": [],
  "synonyms": {},
  "distinctAttribute": null,
  "typoTolerance": {
    "enabled": true,
    "minWordSizeForTypos": {
      "oneTypo": 5,
      "twoTypos": 9
    },
    "disableOnWords": [],
    "disableOnAttributes": []
  },
  "faceting": {
    "maxValuesPerFacet": 100
  },
  "pagination": {
    "maxTotalHits": 1000
  }
}
```

But when I do a query with a date filter I get no results back from production. I have confirmed that the documents I am expecting exist in the index.

`curl -X POST 'http://production/indexes/posts/search' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"q": "hidden", "filter": "created_at > 1039529906"}'`

```
{"hits":[],"query":"hidden","processingTimeMs":3,"limit":20,"offset":0,"estimatedTotalHits":0}
```

Whereas on local it is working fine

`curl -X POST 'http://localhost:7700/indexes/posts/search' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"q": "hidden", "filter": "created_at > 1039529906"}'`

```
{"hits":[...lots of hits returned ...],"query":"hidden","processingTimeMs":1,"limit":20,"offset":0,"estimatedTotalHits":106}
```

There are no tasks currently running, I loaded the documents last night:

`curl -X GET 'http://production/tasks?statuses=processing'`

```
{"results":[],"total":0,"limit":20,"from":null,"next":null}
```

My next step is to kill the index in production and reload the data again. Not sure if this will make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turns to be that I set the `created_at` field to a **string** in the CSV, instead of a **number**.

I deleted the index and recreated and set it up as before. Then recreated and uploaded the CSVs with the `created_at` set as a number and now everything works.